# Java: Calling a method from a wrong class

Tags: java

I am a total newbie in Java and I am trying to write a bouncing ball program. It should create a ball at a pre-determined location on the screen and the ball should bounce it's way off the screen. When I put all the methods in one class, it works perfectly. However, when I try to accomplish the task using two classes, I fail.

Here is the Ball class which basically just creates the new ball:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ball extends GraphicsProgram{

    private GOval ball;
    private int diam;

    public Ball(int width, int height){
        Random rand = new Random();
        diam = rand.nextInt(15) + rand.nextInt(15);
        ball = new GOval(width, height, diam, diam);
        Color c = new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
        ball.setFillColor(c);
        ball.setFilled(true);
        add(ball);
    }

    public Ball(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        diam = rand.nextInt(15) + rand.nextInt(15);
        ball = new GOval(50, 100, diam, diam);
        Color c = new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
        ball.setFillColor(c);
        ball.setFilled(true);
        add(ball);
    }

    public int getDiam(){
        return(diam);
    }
}
```

And here is the class which should extend the Ball class:

```
//import acm.graphics.*;
//import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class BouncingBall extends Ball{

    private final static int START_X = 50;
    private final static int START_Y = 100;

    private final static int GRAVITY = 3;
    private final static double BOUNCE_REDUCE = 0.90;

    private final static int DELAY = 50;

    private final static double X_VEL = 5;

    private double xVel = X_VEL;
    private double yVel = 0.0;

    private Ball ball;
    private int diam;

    public static void main( String[] arg ){
        new BouncingBall().run();
    }

    public void run(){
        setup();
        while(ball.getX() < getWidth()){
            moveBall();
            checkForCollision();
            pause(DELAY);
        }
        remove(ball);
    }

    private void setup(){
        ball = new Ball(START_X, START_Y);
    }

    private void moveBall(){
        yVel += GRAVITY;
        ball.move(xVel, yVel);
    }

    private void checkForCollision(){
        diam = ball.getDiam();
        if (ball.getY() > getHeight() - diam){
            yVel = -yVel * BOUNCE_REDUCE;

            double diff = ball.getY() - (getHeight() - diam);
            ball.move(0, -2 * diff);

            Random rand = new Random();
            Color c = new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
            ball.setFillColor(c);
            c = new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
            setBackground(c);
        }
    }
}
```

What bothers me is the following. I get errors in the BouncingBall class in the line

```
ball.move(xVel, yVel);
```

, line

```
ball.move(0, -2 * diff);
```

and line

```
ball.setFillColor(c);
```

and the error I am getting is "method move in class java.awt.Component cannot be applied to given types;" for the former two occurrences and "cannot find symbol" for the latter one. Both of these are because the move and setFillColor are being looked for in the wrong classes instead of the GObject class which, as far as I get it should provide its methods as inherited to Ball and then - to BouncingBall.

I can't seem to find an explanation as to why aren't the inherited methods being called - I'd be grateful if someone could help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: In the code you've shared there's no method called "move" in the Ball-class

Comment: It would help if we could see the class GraphicsProgram because we do not know how the `move` method is implemented.

Comment: `BouncingBall` is a subclass of `Ball`. Why are you making a private `Ball` variable?

Comment: If you're extending the `Ball` class, I don't understand why you'd have a member of type `Ball`, and with the same name as the one in the `Ball` class. In this case, you're probably getting some errors because you're working on a different type of ball, but I'm not sure. Normally, I would have set the access of `ball` to `protected` instead of `private` and simply used that in the derived class.

Comment: @Marcus: I assumed that the move method would be inherited by Ball from GObject via GOval, as ball is an instance of GOval.

Comment: @maple_shaft: The GraphicsProgram class Javadoc can be found here: http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html

Comment: @unholysampler: I may be misunderstanding the basics here. I create the private Ball variable to tie a Ball instance to it and then to have that instance and store it's position and color during the whole life of the instance.

Comment: @Vlad: I'll try to look into, thanks. I haven't yet met protected variables.

Comment: the ball variable is indeed a GOval but the Ball `class` which the Bouncing ball inherits from is not a GOval.

Comment: @Marcus Yes, thanks I can see that now. Didn't realize that first.

Answer (score 3):

You inherit of course methods from GraphicsProgram to Ball, but assuming this is your GraphicsProgram: http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html it fails because GraphicsProgram does not contain *move* or *setFillColor* methods and also you do not give implementation for such methods.

Comment: Yes, that's my GraphicsProgram. I assumed the Ball would inherit the methods from GObject, but I can see where I was wrong now. I will be now digging in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the method
`ball.move(xVel, yVel);`
where `xVel` and `yVel` are of type `double`. But the method requires two arguments of type `int`.

Please take a look at the relevant [API snippet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#move%28int,%20int%29). You could solve the issue by declaring the variables as `int` or cast the values to `int` before calling the method.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem with ints and doubles, but I was actually trying to call a GObject.move method that requires doubles. otherwise i don't get the needed accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

[Ball.move](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/)
requires integer arguments. Your sending doubles. In `BouncingBall.java`, `ball` is of type `GraphicsProgram`, not `GOval`, which has a method `setFillColor(Color)`.